# How to make an image link in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: image, hyperlink, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I have this code:

```
<div class="first-div-inner"><img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' src="{!! asset('images/add.png') !!}"/></div>
```

I have a route that I want to point to when an image is clicked. Using text, it's simple, but I have not been able to find away around using image as a link

If it is text, it'll be thus

```
{!! Html::linkRoute('myRouteName', 'text to display') !!}
```

How do I substitute the `'text to display'` with an image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain html in cases like this to save some microtime while helpers create the data...

```
<a href="{{ route('name') }}"><img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' src="{{ url('images/add.png') }}"/></a>
```

Or if you still want to use helpers:

```
{!! Html::linkRoute('myRouteName', '<img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' src="' . url('images/add.png') . '"/>') !!}
```